# display count of two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a sql query where exam _invite and interview_invite are two different column in same table. Now I have to count how many were there with exam _invite were Y and how many were there with  interview_invite for ear 2019.

this the query I wrote below

```
select output.acad_year, output.class_name, count(output.exam_invite),count(output.interview_invite)
FROM
(select
    acad.acad_year,
    cls.class_name,
    addr.exam_invite,
    addr.app_status_stage,
    addr.interview_invite

FROM
    tbl_admission_status AS addr
INNER JOIN tbl_stu_application AS app
ON
    app.fk_stu_id = addr.fk_stu_id
INNER JOIN list_acad_years AS acad
ON
    app.fk_acad_year = acad.pk_acad_year_id
INNER JOIN list_class AS cls
ON
    app.fk_class_id = cls.pk_class_id
WHERE
    acad_year = '2022' AND (addr.interview_invite = 'Y'or addr.exam_invite ='Y')) as output
    where output.exam_invite ='Y' and output.interview_invite ='Y'
```

The above query counts the result but it displays both count as 2 instead of 1 in each counts

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Hint:  `COUNT` in MySQL supports SQL expressions like `COUNT(output.exam_invite = 'Y')`. Might be usefull to get the result you need but iam not sure hard to see without example data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(condition1) AS Col_Result_1, COUNT(condition2) AS Col_Result_2
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.col = table2.col
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.